Freezing Ubuntu: RAM fully used and CPU all busy, but active processes don't add up to more than 15% CPU capacity
I have just surface level knowledge about hardware and Ubuntu, so please correct me if I say anything wrong or unlikely.
Since January, I am using a used Dell Latitude 7490. I brought my old laptop (ASUS Zenbook) to be repaired, but they were unable to do so, and sold me this Dell instead. They put both the old RAM and HDD in the new laptop (as far as I can recall). I have dual boot Windows and Ubuntu 22.04 Ubuntu. Ubuntu has 8GB memory and 512GB disk. The processor is Intel i5.
Ever since getting the laptop, Ubuntu has completely frozen at least once a week (had to use alt+sysreq+REISUB to recover). I can't figure out what is clogging the system or what else could be wrong. Just now I noticed the system starting to lag again, but I was able to enter system monitor before it completely froze. The weird thing is that on the Resources tab, the laptop clearly seems very busy with something, however when I look at the Processes tab, no processes seem to take up that much space. Below are screenshots of both tabs.



Run the command htop (if not available install with sudo apt install htop). There you can see all the processes.

And focus on RAM usage, not CPU. That is where the issue will be, probably. I can already see one process using 5G of RAM in your second screenshot. It might also be overheating, is the machine very hot?
